# PHP ZEND create URL with Json value

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am in a CONTROLLER and a ACTION, from a database query execution, and now returns a ARRAY (I want to transfer this data). Now I want to pass this data to a front FLASH (JSON format) with URL. Like URL is / controller/action/new/id/1/, how do this? how can i create url to transfer this value??

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you actually need JSON for your purposes but if you do you can convert an array to JSON:

```
//should work for most objects as well
$array  = array();
$data = Zend_Json::encode($array);
//make the json human readable if required
$pretty = Zend_Json::prettyPrint($data,array($options = NULL))<br />
```

[Zend_Json:: Ref](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.html)
This simplest (but not the only way) way to send information in a url in ZF is to use _forward:
[Zend_Controller_Action() Utility Methods](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.utilmethods)

```
$this->_forward('action', 'controller', 'module', array('key' => 'value');
```

the default for *'controller'* and *'module'* are null